# I need to generate a CSR on my HSM with a critical key usage of Non Repudation?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, key, csr

As above, we were planning to do the following:

- Access our HSM (Luna SA)
- Generate CSR
- Send CSR to 3rd Party CA
- Add critical key usage of Non Repudiation on 3rd Parties portal
- Send the now signed CSR (public key to our trading partner) which has the key usage

Does it matter if I have not added the key usage attribute during the CSR generation on the HSM as I cannot find a way to add the key usage with the HSM client software?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Each tool should be used for what it does the best. The HSM is great to protect a private key by allowing to use it without leaking it out the the hardware module.

But IMHO, the CSR generation and validation should be done before submitting a validated CSR to the HSM for signature only.

Comment: Thankyou, we have found a solution that involves writing a config file to the HSM, this way we can still generate the CSR with the right key usage attribute on the HSM.

Answer (score 1):

It is typically the responsibility of the CA to only sign extensions they approve (typically described in their CPS), and may add extensions according to the type of certificate. I would check with the CA.

For most CAs they will discard the extensions you supply and only add the ones they include from their own template/certificate type. As an example, you may have the CA:TRUE extension in your CSR, but no CA is going to simply sign without first removing that value. On the other hand, if you specifically request a nonRepudiation certificate, the CA should add it for you even if it is not in the CSR, since the resulting certificate will not perform as you require without it.